Magento 2 : Tax Exempt on the Checkout when opt for Tax Exemption
I have to exempt tax for the user if select the tax exemption on the checkout.
For this I have displayed the option to select tax exempt on the Payment step in the Checkout. When user click on select the checkbox and then click on the button then Tax should be 0 and calculate the order total. I have to do this for Guest and Registered customer both.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="tax-exemption" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_TaxExempt/js/checkout/taxExemption</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutcomments</item>
                                                                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>

How can I make the Tax 0? Also it will save the data with customer. So if customer is again going to order then Tax should be 0 on the basis of previously saved Tax Exemption data.
Please give me some suggestion or hints.
